# How to configure fluent nHibernate with MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, autofac

I'm trying to configure nHibernate to use a MySql database. I found examples for mssql and sqlite but none for mysql.
So, how do I change this so it uses mysql:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005.ConnectionString(
            c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString")
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyAutofacModule>())
    .BuildSessionFactory())
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change `MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2005`, to `MySqlConfiguration.Standard`, it was the one thing I contributed to the project.

Example:

```
Fluently.Configure().Database(
        MySqlConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(
            c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("ConnectionString")
        )
    )
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<MyAutofacModule>())
    .BuildSessionFactory())
```

Comment: Thank you, funny I missed this.

Comment: signed in just to vote you guys up. now, can someone help me with nhibernate? i get error unable to create drive for mysql

Comment: Cool, you might want to ask a whole new question with as much details as you can possibly give.  I'm not familiar with that error off hand, so I can't give you much help without more details.  I will say that the error sounds unusual, I don't think I've ever got that one and I mess around with Fluent NHib and MySql all the time.

Comment: Did you need to install any software for this to work?  I'm new to NHibernate and MySQL...  In particular, did you install MySql Connector, and if so what version?

Comment: Yes, I did need a driver from MySql Connector, specifically a reference to MySql.Data.  I don't think the version is relevant as long as it's not an ancient one.  I've never had a problem in terms of which version I was using.  I don't think FluentNhibernate directly references the MySql.Data library, so there should not be a version mismatch.

Comment: @Mark Rogers I'm getting this error when I use your code. Is this an issue with my NHibernate version, or with MySQL? 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'Standard'

Comment: @Chazt3n - The MySql objects may have changed or something.  But I think your connection string builder part needs to have something different where Standard is.  If I had intellisense up I would do MySqlConfiguration. and look to see what was there.  I think i've made a similar change in the past for a sql server connection.

Comment: I actually was able to solve the problem using MySQLcon... instead of MySql... it has had to have changed, because in every resource I see how you have it. Thank you for the response good sir.

Answer (score 0):

```
var SessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard.ConnectionString(connectionString))
    .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()))
    .BuildSessionFactory();`
```

Try this Configuration.