# Using MVC with MySql

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I want to use MVC framework and EntityFramework with MySql. But when i try to select Datasource for changing database and provider , MySql database is not showing. Then how can i select MySql database.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to deal with a MySql database from a .Net application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871751/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-a-mysql-database-from-a-net-application)

Answer (score 0):

You should download mysql connector from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ then add dll-s to your project and use data adapter.

or there is another way in tutorial

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/426790/Using-MySQL-with-Entity-Framework

Comment: Thanks Robert but actually my problem is to select MySql Database while choosing new connection. MySql Database is not showing.